# Properly and efficiently update hundreds of records in sql server db table from .net c# application loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert

I have been using Entity Framework 6 for a while now, typically I update 1 record at a time.

**However, I need to loop over all the users, 300 - 1,000 users**

Is it going to be highly inefficient and slow to update a few columns in the db. with EF6.x ?   Should I use ADO.NET instead or send some sort of object across the wire, some bulk update??

Currently I update like this

```
rpmuser.usr_id = user;
rpmuser = db.rpm_usr.Find(rpmuser.usr_id);
rpmuser.lst_pwd_chg_dtm = dateTime;
rpmuser.cre_dtm = dateTime;

rpmuser.usr_pwd = hash;
rpmuser.salt = salt;

db.SaveChanges();
```

So essentially if I looped over the other users would that be ok?  how else can i do this with bulk update?

```
for( ....  ) {
  // different user id 
  // all the other needed poco model changes above... etc.
  // db.SaveChanges()
}
```

Comment: See the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892410/updating-records-in-foreach-loop-in-entity-framework-6).  It may point you in the right direction.

Comment: If ultimate performance is the goal then write the update statement and pass it to the Db or write a spoc and call that from your code.

Comment: 1,000 records isn't much. Don't do the Find() and SaveChanges() inside the loop - fetch the collection, loop, SaveChanges() once.

Comment: How do I Find(each unique user) without it being in a loop?

Comment: [Table-valued parameters provide an easy way to marshal multiple rows of data from a client application to SQL Server without requiring multiple round trips or special server-side logic for processing the data.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) I have no idea how to use it with EF, I never used EF.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Did you get the answer you need?

Comment: @bwyn    yes  thx bwyn

Comment: Have you actually even tested it to see if it is this huge performance problem you imagine it to be? My first assumption is it wouldn't be anywhere near as bad as you think  and unless you're doing it several times a second you may well spend more time developing a "solution" than EF will ever waste on the "problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to test this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateAndSeedTheDatabase(); // Step 1: run this
    //UpdateAllOfTheProducts(); // Step 2: Comment out the above line and uncomment and run this line
}

static void CreateAndSeedTheDatabase()
{
    Context context = new Context();
    context.Database.Initialize(true);

    Product product;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        product = new Product() { ProductId = i, Name = "Product" + i };
        context.Products.Add(product);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}

static void UpdateAllOfTheProducts()
{
    Context context = new Context();
    Product[] products = context.Products.ToArray();
    foreach (Product product in products)
    {
        product.Name = product.ProductId + "Product";
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: It is not new records that I need to Insert,  but Update,   I had tried to do an   .Add(model)  and SaveChanges()   without updating all the columns and EF thought to tell sql server it was an INSERT statement,   thus I changed it to work by using the Find()  before the SaveChanges()    ,   so I gather I should not do SaveChanges() in the for loop,  but what about the Find(user)   that would get passed to it with an incoming user parameter etc...

Comment: Did you try running this code in a console application? The UpdateAllOfTheProducts method updates all of the existing records in the database created by the CreateAndSeedTheDatabase method.

Answer (score 0):

To properly and efficiently update hundreds of records, you need to reduce database round-trip as much as possible.

In your case, you have two methods making heavy database round-trip

**Find Method**

For every user you need to update, you are making a database roundtrip. There are multiple ways to reduce this quickly.

- Load all users and use a dictionary with the key "usr_id" to make only one database round-trip (Work well if the database doesn't contain millions of users!)
- Create a list with all "usr_id" and retrieve all users at once using the Contains Methods

Example:

```
// Work well if the database doesn't contain to much users
var userDict = db.rpm_usr.ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.usr_id);


// Be careful, the list cannot contains more than 2099 items (SQL Parameters limit = 2100)
var userDict = db.rpm_usr.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.usr_id)).ToDictionary(x => x.usr_id);
```

In both solutions, only one database round-trip will be performed, and you can retrieve the user from the dictionary very efficiently.

**SaveChanges Method**

The SaveChanges methods perform a database round-trip for every record to update. So if you update 1000 users, 1000 database round-trip will be made which is very slow.

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This project allows to performs BulkSaveChanges and BulkUpdate to improve performance dramatically:

```
for( ....  ) {
  // different user id 
  // all the other needed poco model changes above... etc.
  db.BulkSaveChanges()
}

for( ....  ) {
  // different user id 
  // all the other needed poco model changes above... etc.
  db.BulkUpdate(users)
}
```